# Location for .htaccess in NuxtJS SSR build proxied through apache2

Tags: .htaccess, nuxt.js, apache2

After building the NuxtJS website for server-sided rendering(SSR) with `nuxt build` the following directories are created

```
./.nuxt
./.nuxt/dist
```

where should I place the `.htaccess` file which contains the `apache2` configuration.

I m serving the website using `npm start` which is running on `port 3000` and redirecting the traffic to it through `apache2` running on `port 80`

Answer (score 0):

**Simple It is!!**

You put the .htaccess file in the `static` directory of your NuxtJS project

Any config files which should be found under the domain. For example

```
http://example.com/<file>
```

should be placed under static directory of the NuxtJS project.

```
favicon.ico
Robots.txt
.htaccess
```

all these files should be placed in the `static` directory. And these files are mapped as follows.

```
http://example.com/favicon.ico
http://example.com/Robots.txt
http://example.com/.htaccess
```